# whether people create separate application for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

We created a few applications targeting iPhone 3 and iPhone 4. When we tested these apps on iPad, they worked well. We thought we do not need to create separate apps targeting iPad. We went with that decision. A few months later, we realized that the graphics are not looking as good as are on the iPhone. Even the text is not that sharp. Now we are wondering whether to create these apps targeting iPad as well. Do people usually create separate apps for iPhad and iPhone or they just create one for these two platforms? If we need to create separate apps, what is the best way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the images and size for ipad. A few changes in xibs that are for ipad. you can make same app work on iphone as well as ipad...

Check out this Link that convert iphone app to universal ipad apps

[Link here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html)

You can place this condition `if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)` and then load the respective xibs. Hope you are getting my point.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad uses "pixel doubling" to expand an iPhone app to completely fill its screen in 2x mode.  That is usually why it won't look as sharp as a native iPad app.  The best way to answer whether or not you should make an native iPad app is a matter of customer base and funds for R&D.  Do you think your customers will demand (and pay for) a separate app?  Is it worth the additional costs to design, develop, support and maintain it?

Also, do the activities involved in your app scale to the iPad platform?  When I say this I mean are they complex enough where they would benefit from redesigning to accommodate the extra screen space and UI elements the iPad offers?